# Toast Notification not triggering .NET with Angular

Tags: asp.net-core, toast, toastr

Hope someone can help me clarify some doubts I have regarding popups and toasts. I have a .ASPNET Core application with users, I have a change password functionality and i'm trying to send a toastr.success message whenever the password is changed without an issue, how could I do this?

Currently, I have this method when the form is submited:

```
onSubmit() {

this.accountService.changePassword(this.updatePasswordForm.value).subscribe(response => {    
}, error => {
    this.validationErrors = error
})
```

From the component, the form value travels to the account service:

```
changePassword(model: any) {
this.router.navigateByUrl('/member/edit');
return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'account/changePassword', model);
```

And finally from here, to the controller:

```
[HttpPost("changePassword")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ChangePasswordDTO>> ChangePassword([FromBody] ChangePasswordDTO changePassword) {
        //GET CURRENTLY LOGGED IN USER
        var currentUserId = this.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(currentUserId);

        //CHANGE PASSWORD USING USERMANAGER
        var result = await _userManager.ChangePasswordAsync(user, changePassword.OldPassword, changePassword.NewPassword);

        if (!result.Succeeded) {
            return Unauthorized("There was an error changing your password, please try again.");
        } else return Ok("Password changed successfull");
```

When the controller fails to change the password, a toast pops up with the unauthorized message, but on success, nothing happens except the redirect and a console log with a 200 OK message. How and where could I add a success toast if the password is changed successfully?

Thank you for your help in advance!